# What's wrong with my powershell script? :(

Tags: database, powershell, security, download

I'm trying to make an automated script that automatically directs to a
  secure  website in IE, enters login credentials, and goes to a database tab 
  and a database link to download. This will require no user interaction and
  be initiated through windows task scheduler.

However, it works about 75% of the time. I am new to
  powershell and made novice mistakes, so any help or direction would
  greatly be appreciated. Thank you!

```
 PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden {

 function Get-TimeStamp {
 return "[{0:MM/dd/yy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)
                }
 Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Script Executed $dc" | Out-file C:\Users
 \JohnSmith\Desktop\Script\ScriptLog.txt -append

 $username = "admin"
 $password = "admin123"

 $ie = new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application

 #Navigate to the login page
 $ie.navigate("Login Page")
 #Wait for the page to finish loading
 do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))
 $ie.visible = $true #comment this line after debugging

 #Assigning DOM to $doc variable
 $doc = $ie.document

 try {
    $usernameField = $doc.getElementById('userName')  
    #write-host $usernameField
    $usernameField.value = $username
    write-host $username

    $passwordField = $doc.getElementById('password')   
    $passwordField.value = $password
    write-host $pass

    #Find and click the submit button
    $submitButton = $doc.getElementById('login')    
    write-host $submitButton
    $submitButton.click()
    #Wait until login is complete
    do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))

    } catch {$null}

do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Sleep 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~');


$ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate('Database Download' )

while($ie.busy) {sleep 1}
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | where-object
{$_.innerText -eq 'Download the Complete Database'}
$link.click()

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Internet Explorer')
Sleep 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}");

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Internet Explorer')
Sleep 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~');


(New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application').Windows() | Where-Object {
 $_.Name -like '*Internet Explorer*'
 } | ForEach-Object 
 {
 $_.Quit()
[Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($_)
}

[GC]::Collect()
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

 }
```

Comment: Could you add what errors you are getting if any? And what exactly is the result when the script does not work / How do you know it does not work?

Comment: The problem occurs at the secure login page. It sometimes does not select Login after entering credentials.

Comment: Does this line return anything? `Write-Host $submitButton`

Comment: Try replacing `catch {$null}`, if you put an action inside the curly brackets you might see more about the error. E.g. `Write-Host $_.Exception.Message`

Comment: "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms" Put this line on the top of your script and remove any duplicates in the script. What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Here was my finished script. It's not as elegant as I would like it to be, but it does what I need it to do, for now! Thank you!

```
PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden {

function Get-TimeStamp {
return "[{0:MM/dd/yy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)
                   }
#Creates appending log file for everytime script runs
Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Script Executed $dc" | Out-file C:\Users
\JohnSmith\Desktop\DatabaseScript\DatabaseScriptLog.txt -append


$username = "admin"
$password = "admin123"

#write-host $pass
#Create the IE com object
$ie = new-object -com InternetExplorer.Application

#Navigate to the login page
Start-Process 'https://www.LoginPageToTheSecureSite'


<#$ie.navigate("https://www.LoginPageToTheSecureSite")
#Wait for the page to finish loading
do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))
$ie.visible = $true 



#Assign the DOM to the $doc variable
$doc = $ie.document

 try {
 #Find the username field and set the value to that of variable
 $usernameField = $doc.getElementById('User ID')  

  #write-host $usernameField
  $usernameField.value = $username
  write-host $username
  #Find the password field and set the value to that of the result
  #of a call to the get-password function with the parameter defined at
  top

  $passwordField = $doc.getElementById('Password')   

  $passwordField.value = $password
  write-host $pass

  #Submit button 

 $submitButton = $doc.getElementById('Login')    
 write-host $submitButton

 $submitButton.click()
 #Wait until login is complete
 do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))
 } catch {$null}

      #Wait for page to finish loading
      do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))

 $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
 $wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
 Sleep 1
 Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~');


$wshell.AppActivate('Internet Explorer')
Sleep 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Start-Process 'https://www.DownloadTheDatabaseSelectionTab'


$wshell.AppActivate('Internet Explorer')
Sleep 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Start-Process 'https://www.DownloadThisAsZipFile.zip'

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Opening Database Zip File')
Sleep 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~');


$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Internet Explorer')
Sleep 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB 2}");


 #Closes every instance of IE 
 (New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application').Windows() | Where-Object {
 $_.Name -like '*Internet Explorer*'
 } | ForEach-Object {
 $_.Quit()
 }

 #Releases COM Object, cleans up.
 (New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application').Windows() | Where-Object {
 $_.Name -like 'Internet Explorer'
 } | ForEach-Object {
 $_.Quit()
[Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($_)
 }

[GC]::Collect()
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

 }
```